# PWA application does not work without internet

Tags: caching, progressive-web-apps, offline

Can the PWA application work without an internet connection if it is installed from the internet?

I have tried a lot of ways. All without success. As an example, here is one of the URLs from where PWA can be installed: https://sparkvue.pasco.com/.
I install the app via Chrome, after launching it I disconnect the internet, refresh the app window with Ctrl-F5 and get a "You're offline" message.
The app is tightly bound to the URL ("https://sparkvue.pasco.com/") and does not work with cached data.
Thanks for any information!!!

Comment: Screenshot: https://menu16.com/Temp/PWA_OFFLINE.png

Comment: I think you've answered your question. "The app is tightly bound to the URL ("https://sparkvue.pasco.com/") and does not work with cached data." Try the Cache API and Fetch